# Eclipse & PyDev: Access class functions from console/terminal

Tags: python, eclipse, console

In Eclipse, there is the output console at the bottom.
For an existing microcontroller environment, how can i access functions like "readregister" from the device class from that console when the program is running?

In the class of the µC there are several functions like "readregister" "writeregister" (for a connected I²C device) and so on. 
When I start my python script there is an initialization routine and then the script is finished.
If i want to communicate with the I²C device, i have to put all commands in the script.
But how can I execute these functions by entering a command in the IDE's console?

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I don't think there is enough context to know what  you are asking here. Please provide more specific detail, if possible an [MCVE]

Comment: So I updated the description, but no one so far answered. Do you understand it better now?

Comment: I understand a bit better. What you need to do is start a console and then run the python commands in it (like import uC). i.e. you do exactly the same thing in your script, step-by-step, in the console. Have a look at http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html on how to use the console.